# STM8 SWIM interface connection problem

Tags: st-link, stm8

I am trying to connect STM8L052C6T6 microcontroller using SWIM interface (STM8 port) on ST-Link/V2 programmer and it just doesn't connect.

[image]

Power comes from outside power source (target is powered) because doc says Pin1 of the programmer is just for getting voltage reference.

Could someone please point what kind of settings should be inside ST-Link Utility ?

I have tried all combinations of Mode and Reset mode, cannot figure what I am skipping?

[image]

Comment: I"m not familiar with the ST-LINK Utility, but it looks to me as though it's expecting to be talking to an STM32 device and is therefore only offering you JTAG or SWD options, while you need SWIM for your STM8. Do you need to configure the utility somewhere first for your STM8 micro?

Comment: Selected the wrong device

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but following ST-Link manual, this should be it.I have used STM8 port and everything else should work.

Answer (score 3):

I have found solution and want to share it with you.

So, first download STVP-STM8 from:

[ST Website - STVP-STM8](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stvp-stm8.html)

Then install it and start St Visual Programmer

[image]

Select your programmer, in my case ST-Link, then mode (SWIMM) and your microcontroller.
Application opens up and you can read/write microcontroller.

Happy hacking everyone!

Comment: Hey Dude! I just want to say a huge thank you! I was about to give up on a project because i couldn't figure out how to connect the programmer to this part :) You kept my project alive!